# Multiples types were found home controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I need do put a new home in new area but im have a error:
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.
my new area

Areas/Administrativo/Controllers/HomeController

Areas/Administrativo/Views/Home

my AdministrativoAreaRegistration

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Administrativo_default",
            "Administrativo/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

in Global i have

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new[] { "Preparacao.Gerenciar.Web.Controllers" } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the namespace constraint in your area route registration (check if the namespace is correct):

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Administrativo_default",
        "Administrativo/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "Preparacao.Gerenciar.Web.Areas.Administrativo.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

the same way you did with your main route registrations:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },  // Parameter defaults
        new[] { "Preparacao.Gerenciar.Web.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks man I was putting new[] {"Preparacao.Gerenciar.Web.Controllers"} instead of new[] { "Preparacao.Gerenciar.Web.Areas.Administrativo.Controllers" }

Comment: i put this but i get the this error don't work for me, do you have more idea?

Comment: if i put http://localhost/HelpProvasGerenciar/Administrativo/ i get 404 and if http://localhost/HelpProvasGerenciar/ i get multiples types ....

Comment: this works fine just Administrativo but in default localhost/HelpProvas don't work i get error multiples types

Comment: public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new []{ "Preparacao.Gerenciar.Web.Controllers" }
            );
        } my project name is Preparacao.Gerenciar.Web.Controllers

Comment: Did you verify whether the namespace for your HelpProvasController` class is `Preparacao.Gerenciar.Web.Controllers`?

Comment: i don't have HelpProvasController... helpprovas is my virtual directory

Comment: namespace Prepracao.Gerenciar.Web.Controllers from default and namespace Preparacao.Gerenciar.Web.Areas.Administrativo.Controllers

Comment: problems fixed in my home default namespace Prepracao.Gerenciar.Web.Controllers from default and namespace "Prepracao" i put "Preparacao" and it's work fine thanks